# Saving iTextSharp pdf into byte and download with save dialog

Tags: c#, download, itext, memorystream

I'm trying to create pdf using iTextSharp and convert it into byte and download the pdf file with a save dialog. I have used MemoryStream to convert the pdf into byte and used HttpResponse Page method to download the back the pdf file but it don't seem to be working. It don't not have any error and nothing happen after clicking the button.(Using Chrome, FireFox) Do help me out and check which part did I did wrongly. Thanks!

```
protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
byte[] pdfBytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())c
{
    var doc1 = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, ms);
    doc1.Open();

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

    table.TotalWidth = 585f;
    table.LockedWidth = true;

    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell imgCell1 = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell();

    var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/image/logo.jpg"));
    doc1.Add(logo);

    var titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15, Font.BOLD);
    doc1.Add(new Paragraph("Official Report. Member Report ID : " + DDLCase.SelectedValue, titleFont));

    var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD);
    var phrase = new Phrase();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");

    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select lro.fullname, lro.contact, mr.typeofcrime, mr.location,mr.crdatetime, mr.citizenreport, pr.policeid,  pr.prdatetime, pr.policereport, aor.officialreport,  mr.image1, mr.image2, mr.image3, mr.image4, mr.image5,  pr.image1, pr.image2, pr.image3, pr.image4, pr.image5 from MemberReport mr, PoliceReport pr, LoginRegisterOthers lro, AdminOfficialReport aor where mr.memberreportid = '" + DDLCase.SelectedValue + "' and mr.memberreportid=pr.memberreportid and pr.policereportid=aor.policereportid", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr;

    dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Full Name :", normalFont));
        phrase.Add(dr[0].ToString());

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Contact :", normalFont));
        phrase.Add(dr[1].ToString());

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Type Of Crime :", normalFont));
        phrase.Add(dr[2].ToString());

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Location :", normalFont));
        phrase.Add(dr[3].ToString());

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Citizen Report Date Time :", normalFont));
        phrase.Add(dr[4].ToString());

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Citizen Report :", normalFont));
        phrase.Add(dr[5].ToString());

        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        phrase.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Citizen Images :", normalFont));

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("1.", normalFont));
        Byte[] bytes1 = (Byte[])dr[10];
        iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes1);
        image1.ScaleToFit(1150f, 1150f);
        Chunk imageChunk1 = new Chunk(image1, 0, 0);
        phrase.Add(imageChunk1);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("2.", normalFont));
        Byte[] bytes5 = (Byte[])dr[11];
        iTextSharp.text.Image image5 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes5);
        image5.ScaleToFit(1150f, 1150f);
        Chunk imageChunk5 = new Chunk(image5, 0, 0);
        phrase.Add(imageChunk5);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("3.", normalFont));
        Byte[] bytes6 = (Byte[])dr[12];
        iTextSharp.text.Image image6 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes6);
        image6.ScaleToFit(1150f, 1150f);
        Chunk imageChunk6 = new Chunk(image6, 0, 0);
        phrase.Add(imageChunk6);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("4.", normalFont));
        Byte[] bytes7 = (Byte[])dr[13];
        iTextSharp.text.Image image7 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes7);
        image7.ScaleToFit(1150f, 1150f);
        Chunk imageChunk7 = new Chunk(image7, 0, 0);
        phrase.Add(imageChunk7);

        phrase.Add(new Chunk("5.", normalFont));
        Byte[] bytes8 = (Byte[])dr[14];
        iTextSharp.text.Image image8 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes8);
        image8.ScaleToFit(1150f, 1150f);
        Chunk imageChunk8 = new Chunk(image8, 0, 0);
        phrase.Add(imageChunk8);

        table.AddCell(phrase);
    }
    dr.Close();
    doc1.Add(table);
    doc1.NewPage();
    doc1.Add(table2);
    doc1.Close();

    pdfBytes = ms.ToArray();
}

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Report.pdf"));
Response.OutputStream.Write(pdfBytes, 0, pdfBytes.Length);  
}
```

I test it using IE get this error:

JScript anonymous function [MicrosoftAjax.js] Line 6    Script

Sorry guy there no error in the code just that this code don't work with AJAX control UpdatePanel. Thank for viewing, helping.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 string fileName = string.Format(Guid.NewGuid()+".pdf");
 htmlToPdf(Server.MapPath(@"~\temp\") + fileName);
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
 Response.End();
```